# How to get the page numbers within the margins specified in the settings in Lyx?

Tags: margins, lyx, page-numbering

I have specified the right, left, top and bottom margins in the Lyx settings under Page margins, but the page numbers appear outside those margins. How can I force the page numbers to be within the margins?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are you, apart from the margins, using the default layout? Try adding `includefoot` to the custom class options, in Document --> Settings --> Document class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply!!! Yes, I am using the default layout (I think...: document class: article, and in Class options, the Predifined grey box is ticked). However, when I put " Custom: includefoot ", I cannot compile the doc into pdf anymore. It reports hundreds of errors (eg too many unprocessed floats, undefined control sequence, etc). Shall I add includefoot somewhere else? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard/impossible to say what causes this without more information. Can you create a sample LyX file with the exact same settings as your original file, so that the problem is seen, but with the contents replaced by some filler text? Having done that, open the `.lyx` file in a text editor (e.g. Notepad), copy the entire contents of the file (it's just text) and edit your question to include this.